# How to multithread a scapy handshake

Tags: python, multithreading, tcp, scapy, handshake

I've got the following lines of code that wait for a connection by a client:

```
connfilter = "tcp[tcpflags] & (tcp-syn) != 0 and dst port " + str(hostport)
connreq = sniff(filter = connfilter, prn = handshake)
```

For every packet a handshake will be required and an html page will be send. The handshake function works fine, until MULTIPLE clients connect at the same time.

WHY?
Because the function will only be called again when the previous handshake is complete. This causes the client to time out if it has not been handshaked in time. Scapy simply waits for a response for a bizarre long time.

How can I multithread this?